# Exclude current node from entity reference view (for related news)

Tags: views, entities

In Drupal 7 I have a news content type with a simple related news selection list. This works like a charm, I use an entity reference view to fill the list and new news-items are created just like they should be. But once the news-item is published it will of course be shown in the list. If you select it, the standard behaviour will be to render its full content view, resulting in a recursive content error.

How can I create an entity reference view that excludes the current node? I have found a lot of related issues, but nobody seems to answer the question of using parameters at all in this special kind of view. I tried to add an argument to the filter using the token syntax which says "AND Nid not equals [node:id]" but that turns out to be ignored. I also found that when you include the view it is possible to send parameters to it, but I was unable to find documentation for how to use them.

Does anybody have more information/documentation about this?

Answer (score 1):

there is a patch fixing that issue and helping you to use `[node:nid]` as an arg [here](http://drupal.org/node/1699378#comment-6809760).

---

Otherwise, did you try [Entity Reference View Widget](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference_view_widget) ?

> The module has a way of hiding selected items from the View. Simply
>   add a base field contextual argument (Product ID for products, Node ID
>   for nodes, etc) and in the "More" fieldset enable "Allow multiple
>   values" and "Exclude". Then edit the Entity Reference field, and in
>   the widget settings enable "Pass selected entity ids to View ".

Comment: Thanks for the leads, I will look into it further. At the very least I misspelled nid as id there. Still I probably need the patch. Do you also have a hint of where to find more info about how to use submitted arguments from the content type?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly ?

Comment: I just want to know how the argument system for entity reference works at all. It's a bit weird that there is no documentation for such a potentially powerful feature.

Comment: I don't really know, usually I set a custom PhP filter (or a contextual filter with php "when argument is not available") and use current_path, get the nid out of it and load it. I'd advise you to do the same, it's the simpliest for that use.

Comment: I am using aliases and clean URL's, how can I get the nid out of the path then? Also it seems like a hacky solution if there is an internal parameter passing mechanism.

Comment: By the way, I could not get the Entity reference view widget to display, although I follow the advice in the README.

Comment: You can get actual node by doing `$path = explode('/', current_path()); $nid = $path[2];` . More info on current_path() [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/request_uri/7#comment-40018)